# Downloading empty pdf in VueJS

Tags: c#, vue.js, pdf

I download the pdf file but it is empty.
When I open it I get this

> Failed to load PDF document.

This is my BE:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/contract-agreement")]
[Produces("text/html", "application/pdf", Type = typeof(FileContentResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, Type = typeof(ValidationErrorResponse))]
public async Task<FileContentResult> GetContractAgreementAsync([FromRoute] string id, GetOverdraftContractAgreementRequest request)
{
    var query = new GetOverdraftContractAgreementQuery(
        id,
        request.ContentType.ToMimeContentType());

    var result = await Mediator.Send(query);
    return File(result.Content, result.MimeContentType);
}
```

This is my VueJS template:

```
<template>
  <div class="overdraft-documents-wrapper">
    <b-button-group>
      <div v-if="documents.contract">
        <button @click="exportFile(documents.overdraftId, 'contract.pdf')" class="btn btn-info documents-btn mr-3">Download Contract</button>
      </div>
      <div v-if="documents.sef">
        <button @click="exportFile(documents.overdraftId, 'sef.pdf')" class="btn btn-info documents-btn">Download SEF</button>
      </div>
    </b-button-group>
  </div>
</template>
```

And those are my methods:

```
async exportFile (document, fileName) {
      if (fileName === 'contract.pdf') {
        this.mergeFilters(document)
        await this.fetchContractAgreement({ id: document, filters: this.filters }).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          this.downloadFile2(response, fileName)
        })


downloadFile2 (res, fileName) {
  const fileURL = `data:application/pdf;,${res}`
  const fileLink = document.createElement('a')
  fileLink.href = fileURL
  fileLink.setAttribute('download', fileName)
  document.body.appendChild(fileLink)
  fileLink.click()
},
```

Please help. I do not understand what seems to be the error. I have spent 2 days on this.

When I call this endpoint in postman it successfully returns the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

In Vuejs template you have to define `responseType` in axios call, try this instead

```js
    axios({
    url: "",
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "blob", // important
    }).then((response) => {});
```

Response type `blob` is very important when you are handling files such as pdf/images.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).